# Input fields are not updated by useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

**What's the goal?**

I've two inputs and four radio buttons. If you choose each radio button value, it'll be added to the inputs.

**What's my issue?**

The inputs do not update when I choose each radio button.

**What I'm using for my example?**

I'm using both of useState and useRef because I know useRef doesn't update components and useState does it.

**What's weird in this example?**

When I declare a count variable and I add `console.log(count + 1)` above each input field they updated.

the last question. **Why are my input fields updating by `console.log(count + 1)` and not by useState?**

[**CodeSandBox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-leftpad-9klgy?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Form, Input, InputNumber, Radio } from "antd";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const marketCapButtonValue = useRef();
  const marketCapButtonValue1BTo10B = useRef();
  const marketCapButtonValue100MTo1B = useRef();
  const marketCapButtonValue10MTo100M = useRef();

  const [marketCapFrom, setMarketCapFrom] = useState(0);
  const [marketCapTo, setMarketCapTo] = useState(0);
  let count = 0;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  function radioButtonValueHandler(e) {
    console.log("value choosed : ", e.target.defaultValue);
    if (e.target.defaultValue === "10B") {
      marketCapValueHandler(marketCapButtonValue.current.props.value);
    } else if (e.target.defaultValue === "1B - 10B") {
      marketCapValueHandler(marketCapButtonValue1BTo10B.current.props.value);
    } else if (e.target.defaultValue === "100M - 1B") {
      marketCapValueHandler(marketCapButtonValue100MTo1B.current.props.value);
    } else if (e.target.defaultValue === "10M - 100M") {
      marketCapValueHandler(marketCapButtonValue10MTo100M.current.props.value);
    }
  }
  const marketCapValueHandler = (value) => {
    if (value === "10B") {
      setMarketCapFrom(10000000000);
      setMarketCapTo(0);
    } else if (value === "1B - 10B") {
      setMarketCapFrom(1000000000);
      setMarketCapTo(10000000000);
    } else if (value === "100M - 1B") {
      console.log("100M - 1B");
      setMarketCapFrom(100000000);
      setMarketCapTo(1000000000);
    } else if (value === "10M - 100M") {
      console.log("10M - 100M");
      setMarketCapFrom(10000000);
      setMarketCapTo(100000000);
    }
  };
 

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Form form={form} layout="vertical" name="userForm">
        <Input.Group size="large">
          <Row gutter={8}>
            <Col>
              <Form.Item
                name="marketCapFrom"
                rules={[
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input right number."
                  },
                  ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
                    validator(_, value) {
                      if (getFieldValue("marketCapFrom") > 0) {
                        return Promise.resolve();
                      } else if (
                        getFieldValue("marketCapFrom") < 0 ||
                        getFieldValue("marketCapFrom") === null
                      ) {
                        return Promise.reject(
                          new Error("Not null or negative value.")
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  })
                ]}
              >
          {console.log(count + 1)}
               
                <InputNumber
                  size="large"
                  style={{ width: "200px" }}
                  defaultValue={marketCapFrom}
                  value={marketCapFrom}
                  name="marketCapFrom"
                  formatter={(value) =>
                    `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
                  }
                  parser={(value) => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, "")}
                />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col span={2} style={{ textAlign: "center", lineHeight: "2.5" }}>
              <span>To</span>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Form.Item
                name="marketCapTo"
                rules={[
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input right number."
                  },
                  ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
                    validator(_, value) {
                      if (getFieldValue("marketCapTo") > 0) {
                        return Promise.resolve();
                      } else if (
                        getFieldValue("marketCapTo") < 0 ||
                        getFieldValue("marketCapTo") === null
                      ) {
                        return Promise.reject(
                          new Error("Not null or negative value.")
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  })
                ]}
              >
          {console.log(count + 1)}

                <InputNumber
                  size="large"
                  style={{ width: "200px" }}
                  name="marketCapToo"
                  value={marketCapTo}
                  defaultValue={marketCapTo}
                  formatter={(value) =>
                    `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
                  }
                  parser={(value) => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, "")}
                />
              </Form.Item>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <br />

          <Row>
            <Radio.Group defaultValue="10B" buttonStyle="solid" size="large">
              <Radio.Button
                value="10B"
                ref={marketCapButtonValue}
                onClick={radioButtonValueHandler}
              >
                {">"}$10B
              </Radio.Button>
              <Radio.Button
                onClick={radioButtonValueHandler}
                value="1B - 10B"
                ref={marketCapButtonValue1BTo10B}
              >
                $1B - $10B
              </Radio.Button>
              <Radio.Button
                onClick={radioButtonValueHandler}
                ref={marketCapButtonValue100MTo1B}
                value="100M - 1B"
                defaultValue="100M - 1B"
              >
                $100M - $1B
              </Radio.Button>
              <Radio.Button
                onClick={radioButtonValueHandler}
                ref={marketCapButtonValue10MTo100M}
                value="10M - 100M"
                defaultValue="10M - 100M"
              >
                $10M - $100M
              </Radio.Button>
            </Radio.Group>
          </Row>
        </Input.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please **reduce** your problem to an [mre], rather than asking people to read through reams of code...

Comment: ... From your description, I'd think you could replicate the problem in roughly 10-20 lines of code. Please consider using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to show the problem with a runnable example. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: *"Why are my input fields updating by console.log(count + 1) and not by useState?"* Nothing in your code uses `count` on an input.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm using the Ant design library and of course, I check stack snippets before asking a question. it doesn't support ant design.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you're mistaken about that, but regardless, it doesn't prevent you from **reducing** your problem to a [mre], it just means you won't be providing a runnable one and thus maximizing your odds of getting good answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I added  `{console.log(count + 1)}` above each input.

Comment: Yes, which has nothing to do with the inputs. All it does is output a value that's reset on every render.

Comment: To be clear: **I'd like to help** (as you can tell from the > 20k answers I've provided here over the years). To do that, I need something clear and focussed, not a wall of code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Please allow me to clear my code.

Comment: why you use value in your input number ? you are using antd form and you should using the form to update the inputs not the value of the input number

Comment: @HDM91, For updating the value of input numbers, I used useState. Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are using the antd form update the inputs value from the form instance not the value of each input otherwise you can use some input without any antd form:

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cookies-8fu9c?file=/src/App.js:1150-1681)

```
  const marketCapValueHandler = (value) => {
    if (value === "10B") {
      form.setFieldsValue({marketCapFrom:10000000000, marketCapTo:0 })
    } else if (value === "1B - 10B") {
      form.setFieldsValue({marketCapFrom:1000000000, marketCapTo:10000000000 })
    } else if (value === "100M - 1B") {
      form.setFieldsValue({marketCapFrom:100000000, marketCapTo:1000000000 })
    } else if (value === "10M - 100M") {
      form.setFieldsValue({marketCapFrom:10000000, marketCapTo:100000000 })
    }
  };
```